# ngFileUpload with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I wanted to upload file when i submit the form. I am using ngFileUpload at the front end and server is on rails. Following is the code the i have written :

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.username"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.address">
   <input type="file" id="map" ngf-select ng-model="data.map" name="file"
               accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB"
               ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
</form>
```

On form submit, i could see the data(on browser console) object containing all the values(including the object of map/image). But when i check on server side, map is showed as {} i.e empty object.

Could someone help me resolve the same.

Comment: Can you show us your controller code that handles the file upload please. Personally I would just use paperclip or carrierwave to handle file uploads as these are the go to gems for a rails application

Comment: At the controller side, i have called an API,passing data object as my POST data. The data object also includes the map object.  The code goes like:
`var request = $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/myapi/post',
   data: data
})

return req.then(function(resp){
    return resp;
})

`

Comment: Ok, so you are saving your file to a model yes? What about your permitted_params, seeing your complete controller code would help, just update the question with this controller code

Comment: yes..i am saving the file to the 'data' model. So i think the model object is sent as an empty object for the file, as we have to upload it. Can i upload it while sending/submitting the form ?

Comment: Just use paperclip, far simpler than what you are trying to do

Comment: The other thing you should think about is where to store your files, an AWS bucket is a good place and again paperclip will carry a lot of the weight for you

Answer (score 1):

ngUpload can be a pain sometimes.  Here's a solution that we use working with ngUpload and Rails.  Short answer, you need to make sure you are using the `Upload.upload` function to send the attachment to the server.

html

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit(data)">
    ...
   <input type="file" id="map" ngf-select ng-model="data.map" name="file"
               accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB"
               ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
</form>
```

js

```
   $scope.submit = function(data) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/data.json',
            data: {
                data: data
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
           // handle success
        }, function(err) {
           // handle error
        });
    }
```